# Jquery/Javascript to allow selection of multiple ddl values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

The example one I am going to give is a county ddl which has multiple counties. I'm looking to be able to select multiple counties. Adding "multiple: true" to the select tag does not work. I was looking to find a way through query and javascript.

This is my select_tag -
`= select_tag(:county_ddl, raw("<option value='@county'>#{@default_county}</option>"), { :id=>'county_ddl'})`

JS function to update ddl -
`function update_county() {`
`$("#county").val($("#county_ddl").val());`

This is @county -
`@county = County.select(:county).find_by_county(params[:county])&.county`

This is @default_county -
`@default_county  = @county.blank? ? 'Select County' : @county`

Comment: What library are you using to build the `select` element? You've not tagged what it is.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, I'm very new to all of this. If there was a way to do it through html that would be even better.

Comment: Update- I am using the chosen library so usual syntax is "class: 'chosen-select', multiple: true"